# Vector notation - work done by spring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, vectors, spring

I am confused about the work done by spring force in vector notation 
dW=F.dS , where dW= small work done, F=Force , dS= displacement.

Suppose spring is kept along x axis and tied at one end by wall (Left end and natural length is at x=0.

Case 1) Spring is compressed up to x= -x0 
 F= -kx , what will be direction of F vector for calculating the work 
by above dot product ? +i^ or -i^

dx vector-- what will be the direction of dx +i^ or -i^

Case 2)
A compressed spring is released from x=-x0 
 F= -kx , what will be direction of F? +i^ or -i^

--- dx vector, what will be the direction of dx +i^ or -i^

please help for calculating work done by the spring in above two cases

Comment: You need to add a very important clarification:   do you want the work done by the compressing force, or the work done by the spring?

Comment: i want to calculate work done by the spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the right end of the spring is moved to the left a distance $x$, the force that the spring exerts at its right end is $\mathbf{F}=kx\mathbf{i}$. The differential displacement of the spring is $\mathbf{ds}=\mathbf{-i}dx$.  So the work done by the spring in displacing its right end a total distance $x_o$ to the left is $$W=\int_0^{x_o}\mathbf{F}\centerdot \mathbf{ds}=-k\frac{x_0^2}{2}$$This means that work is being done on the spring.

In case 2, the force in the spring is still $\mathbf{F}=kx\mathbf{i}$, but it is being displaced to the right (so dx is negative), and the work done by the spring is then $$W=\int_{x_0}^{0}\mathbf{F}\centerdot \mathbf{ds}=+k\frac{x_0^2}{2}$$

ADDENDUM

The easiest thing is to let the mathematics do the work for you.  Let x represent the displacement of the right end of the spring to the right; then, if the displacement is negative, x is a negative number.  Either way, the force exerted by the spring and the incremental displacement are $$\mathbf{F}=-kx\mathbf{i}$$and$$\mathbf{ds}=\mathbf{i}dx$$So, the differential work done by the spring is $$dW=-kxdx$$The work done by the spring in displacing the right end from x = 0 to x = -$x_0$ is thus:
$$W=\int_0^{-x_0}{(-kxdx)}=-k\frac{x_0^2}{2}$$And the work done by the spring in displacing the right end from x = -$x_0$ to x = 0 is:
$$W=\int_{-x_0}^0{(-kxdx)}=+k\frac{x_0^2}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks Miller for explanation,how to do it using general form of spring force F=-kx ?

Comment: I will amend my answer soon to address that.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show you that the work done by a spring is given by the equation $\displaystyle -\int_{x_{\rm start}}^{x_{\rm finish}} k\,x\,dx $ where 
$x_{\rm start},\, x_{\rm finish},\, x$ and $dx$ are all components of vectors  $\vec x_{\rm start},\, \vec x_{\rm finish},\,  \vec x$ and $d\vec x$ in the direction $\hat x$ and the free end of the unextended spring is located at $\vec x = \vec 0$ or $x=0$.

The force exerted by a spring is $-k\, \vec x = -k\,x\, \hat i$.
If $x$ is positive with the string being stretched the force exerted by the spring is in the $-\hat i$ direction ie pointing towards the origin.
If $x$ is negative with the string being compressed the force exerted by the spring is in the $+\hat i$ direction ie pointing towards the origin.

Suppose the free end of the spring is at position $\vec x = x \,\hat i$ and undergoes a displacement $d\vec x = dx \, \hat i$.
The force exerted by the spring is $-k \vec x$ and the work done by the spring is

$-k\vec x \cdot d\vec x= -k \, x \,\hat i \cdot dx\,\hat i = - k\,x\, dx$

Note that this is an equation which will work for all eventualities.

You have asked:

> Spring is compressed up to x= -x0 F= -kx , what will be direction of F
>   vector for calculating the work by above dot product ? +i^ or -i^

My answer is that the component of force in the $\hat i$ direction will be positive because $\vec F_{\text{due to spring}} = = -k\vec x = -k\,x\,\hat x$ noting that $x$ will have a negative value.

You have asked:

> dx vector-- what will be the direction of dx +i^ or -i^

$d\vec x = \vec x_{\text{changed by a small amount}} - \vec x_{\text{original}} = x_{\text{changed by a small amount}} \hat i- x_{\text{original}} \hat i = \left (x_{\text{changed by a small amount}} - x_{\text{original}} \right) \hat i$

So the direction of $d \vec x$ will be determined by the sign of $\left (x_{\text{changed by a small amount}} - x_{\text{original}} \right)$.

work done by spring is $\displaystyle -\int_{x_{\rm start}}^{x_{\rm finish}} k\,x\,dx $

where the end of the spring starts at $\vec x_\rm {start} = x_\rm {start} \hat i$ and finishes at $\vec x_\rm {finish} = x_\rm {finish} \hat i$

However the key point I am trying to make is that you do not need to worry about the direction of $\vec F_{\text{due to spring}}$ and the direction of $d\vec x$ as all of that will done for you when you do the integration.

---

Your example is of an uncompressed spring $x_{\rm start} = 0$ being compressed to $x_{\rm finish} = -x_0$.

The work done by the spring is  $\displaystyle -\int_0^{{-x_0}} k\,x\,dx = - \dfrac 12 k x_0^2$

If you now reverse the process with $x_{\rm start} = -x_0$ being compressed to $x_{\rm finish} = 0$ and use the work done by the spring equation you will get $+ \dfrac 12 k x_0^2$

Try the same for the spring being stretched where now you have the component of $\vec x$ being positive.

---

My advice is get the general equation for the work done and apply it the situation at hand.